# What is the error of this sql.. pls help me.. In OR

Tags: java, sql

```
SELECT StudentNo,
       Lastname,
       Firstname,
       Middlename,
       Section,
       OrgFee,
       Subject,
       Subject1,
       Subject2,
       Subject3,
       Subject4,
       Subject5
  FROM Enroll
 WHERE Subject or Subject1LIKE '" + subj.getText() + "%'"
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: Could it be that you have `Subject1LIKE` instead of `Subject1 LIKE` with a space in between?

Comment: ... and forgot a quote at the beginning. A lot of errors.

Comment: Your WHERE clause is all wonky. Subject should be evaluated to something. Subject1 and LIKE need a space between, and your quotes are mismatched, so I'm not sure what you are doing there.

Comment: I have erron in or..

Comment: Yes, you have that error because that's not how it's supposed to be used.

Comment: String sql2 = "SELECT StudentNo, Lastname, Firstname, Middlename,Section,OrgFee,Subject,Subject1,Subject2,Subject3,Subject4,Subject5 FROM Enroll WHERE Subject LIKE '" + subj.getText() + "%'";

Comment: where column1 or column2

Comment: `WHERE` doesn't work like that. It should be `WHERE <condition1> OR <condition2>`. You currently have `WHERE column1 OR <bad_sql_statement>`.

Comment: `WHERE Subject LIKE '" + subj.getText() + "%'"` that is invitation for SQL-injection. Use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead. Also what are you trying to accomplish with `...WHERE Subject or...`? What is `Subject` and how this part should be interpreted?

Comment: its the row in access.. Subject1(row1), Subject2(row2)

Comment: Is Subject a boolean column? (If not, you need to modify it's condition in the WHERE clause.)

Answer (score -1):

I think this may help you.

```
SELECT StudentNo, Lastname, Firstname, Middlename, Section, OrgFee, 
       Subject, Subject1, Subject2, Subject3, Subject4, Subject5 
  FROM Enroll 
 WHERE Subject or Subject1 LIKE '"%" + subj.getText() + "%"'
```

You need to add `%` sign before and after the `subj.getText()` and also there is no space after `subject1`